# Excel list dependent on Vlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a table.

```
-----------------------
| Column 1 | Column 2 |
-----------------------
| A        |     X    |
-----------------------
| B        |     R    |
-----------------------
| C        |     T    |
-----------------------
| A        |     Y    |
-----------------------
| B        |     Q    |
-----------------------
| A        |     Z    |
-----------------------
```

I have created a drop-down list in excel for "Column 1", but I would like another list that would display all values for whatever was select from "Column 1" e.g. if "A" was selected, I would then only have the options "X, Y, Z" available for selection.

I looked online for a solution but none work like above.

Is there any way to complete this in Data Validation?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the tutorial on this website might help http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html

Comment: well your title suggests vlookup, but vlookup will only return the first instance found. You could go into using a combination of Index and Match. Making use of Count to see how many instances there are to display.

Comment: @Roosz0rd I was looking at that tutorial but that won't work for this scenario.

Comment: @Luuklag yeah I was going to use Vlookup, but obviously can't because of only the first instance is returned. I will look into an alternative like you said,

Comment: Okay, if you aren't wanting a dependant data validation, I assume then that you want a concatenated list of all potential results in column 2? If so can you provide a basic example of how the data is formatted and I can walk you through what you want to be looking for. If you simply just want another drop-down of validation, that is exactly what the first tutorial shows you. You could tie in `INDEX()` / `VLOOKUP()` to produce the lists that you use for the validation, but to my knowledge there is no method that doesn't require a fair bit of manual administration.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a data validation drop-down, maybe you could use slicers instead!

First filter your data as a table, then under table tools "Insert Slicer" insert two slicers, one for Column 1 and one for Column 2:

[Screenshot (1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RR58q.png)

And then right click on the "Column 2" Slicer, in "Slicer Settings" choose "Hide Items with no data" and then when you select "A" in the Column1 slicer, the Column2 Slicer will be filtered to "X,Y,Z"

[Screenshot (2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLdZF.png)

Hope this helps!